# What does the w value of the GL_Positions' vec4 stand for?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

Writing some GLSL and noticed the return value in my Vertex shader is a vec4 when Im retuning a x,y,z coordinate. I don't believe it to be alpha, and reading on the web its got something to do with clipping?

Comment: These resources on homogeneous coordinates might be of help: [simplified](http://sunshine2k.blogspot.mx/2011/12/reason-for-homogeneous-4d-coordinates.html) and [detailed](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348a-09-fall/Handouts/handout15.pdf)